# can I get market data from chainlink and how?

Tags: chainlink, data

I need to get price market cap and price change of cryptos do you know any free plans and how what limitations do they have?

Answer (score 0):

[Chainlink Data Feeds](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds#price-feeds) dont cost you.  Encourage you to read the docs.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I need API's in a special case for showing market data like listing coins and tokens according to marketcap or price change from the docs i can not find such api. I would appreciate more help. Thanks

Comment: @NIMAShahahmadian the question is not very specific but from what you've indicated there is no one API for that.   But it seems exactly what Chainlink Functions was built for - a way to roll your own "api" if you want to get that kind of data.  Take a look at https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions.